# Expand python statements

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to expand the following statement into multiple lines.

```
words = np.asarray(row1)
m = -1*np.array([[calc(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])
```

Please help me

Comment: Use nested `for` loops. Not sure how much more help we can give without actually doing it for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "expand"? Format it or rewrite it another way?

Comment: The only way to no longer be new is to read tutorials and try to do things yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although I haven't tested it. You need to break down each part of the list comprehension into a 'regular' for loop.

```
words = np.asarray(row1)
m = np.array()
for w1 in words:
    for w2 in words:
       m.append(calc(w1,w2))

m *= -1
```

Comment: `m.append(-calc(w1,w2))` ?

Comment: @DYZ It is equivalent.

Comment: I know. But it is one line shorter.